# Evaluating Function of Incomplete Elliptic Integrals

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematica, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to write Mathematica code that evaluates the following function:

$$
f(\kappa_{yx}, \kappa_{zx}) = 1 + 3 \kappa_{yx} \kappa_{zx} \frac{E(\varphi \backslash \alpha) - F(\varphi \backslash \alpha)}{(1-\kappa_{zx}^2)\sqrt{1-\kappa_{yx}^2}}
$$

where $E(\varphi \backslash \alpha)$ and $F(\varphi \backslash \alpha)$ are the incomplete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, and $\varphi$ and $\alpha$ are defined according to:

$$
\sin{\varphi} = \sqrt{1-\kappa_{yx}^2}
$$

$$
\sin^2{\alpha} = \frac{1-\kappa_{zx}^2}{1-\kappa_{yx}^2}
$$

$\kappa_{yx}$ and $\kappa_{zx}$ are non-negative real numbers (i.e. can take on values greater than one). I need to evaluate the function $f$ because it appears in the equation of motion I'm trying to numerically integrate.

The paper I found the function $f$ in claims it is smooth and ranges from $-2$ to $1$, however Mathematica fails to evaluate the function at $\kappa_{yx} = 1$, $\kappa_{zx}=1$, or any values for which $\kappa_{yx}>1$.

I'm wondering if anyone can provide any guidance on how I can implement the function so that it returns real values for $\kappa_{yx}$ and $\kappa_{zx}$ greater than or equal to unity.

For reference, the paper provides the following plot of the function ( [Log plot of function $f$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s5VY.png) )

The paper also includes a polynomial approximation for the function that works well around unity but I need to evaluate the function when the arguments are around 2 or 3.

Here's the link to the paper: https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.74.013621

Comment: $\sin{\alpha}^2 = \frac{1-\kappa_{yx}^2}{1-\kappa_{yx}^2}=1$. Typo?

Comment: Fixed, thank you.

Comment: What is $\sin{\alpha}^2$? Is it $\sin(\alpha^2)$, or is it $\sin^2(\alpha)$

Comment: Corrected @gpmath

Comment: The paper is not open-access. Could you precise the notation (or better the definition) for the elliptic integrals since there are two of them. Could you also replace $\kappa_{yx}$ by (say) $y$  and  $\kappa_{zz}$ by $z$ for example ? I would be easier. Thanks. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*